# Override Info, Warn, Error of a third party library logging

Tags: python, overriding, intercept, python-logging

I am new to Python (background is .Net) and working on a Python application that is a wrapper around a third-party library.  The third-party Python library uses standard logging. I need to intercept these logging calls and store them.  The code looks something like this:

**Third-party main — myApp.py:**

```py
# Standard Library
import logging

from options import (info, warn)
from process import (processIt)

# Module-level logger
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.propagate = False

formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(name)s] [%(levelname)-7s] [%(asctime)s] %(message)s")

# Console Handler for Elevator messages
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(ch)


def runIt():
        info("Running it.", 1)
        processIt()
        info("Running it.", 2)
```

**Third-party logging setup — options.py:**

```py
# Standard Library
import logging

formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(name)s] [%(ecode)d] [%(levelname)-7s] [%(asctime)s] %(message)s")

# Console Handler for Elevator messages
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# Module-level logger
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.level= logging.INFO
# temporary? hack to prevent multiple loggers from printing messages
log.propagate = False
log.addHandler(ch)


def info(fmt, ecode, *args):
    log.info(fmt, *args, extra={'ecode': ecode})


def warn(fmt, ecode, *args):
    log.warning(fmt, *args, extra={'ecode': ecode})


def init():    
    info("Initialized options", 100)
```

**Third-party process — process.py:**

```py
from options import (info, warn)


def processIt():
  info ("Inside Process", 10)
```

**This is the client — client.py:**

```py
import options
import myApp

info_msg = []
warn_msg = []


def info(fmt, ecode, *args):
    info_msg.append(dict({ecode:fmt.format(*args)}))


def warn(fmt, ecode, *args):
    warn_msg.append(dict({ecode:fmt.format(*args)}))

options.warn = warn
options.info = info


def runApp():  
  print ("Start")
  options.init()
  myApp.runIt()
  print ("End")
  print (info_msg)
  print (warn_msg)


runApp()
```

Here is the output:

```
Start
[options] [1] [INFO   ] [2022-06-09 09:28:46,380] Running it.
[options] [10] [INFO   ] [2022-06-09 09:28:46,380] Inside Process
[options] [2] [INFO   ] [2022-06-09 09:28:46,380] Running it.
End
[{100: 'Initialized options'}]
[]
```

You can see that the log in the init folder got overridden, but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation and quick-and-dirty solution

First of all, your solution is a bit of a hack, since you're modifying a third-party module at runtime. This might work, but it depends on the situation. The reason it does not work in this case, is because **myApp.py** contains `from options import (info, warn)`. In general, using the `from ... import ...` style is not recommended, since this creates additional objects. In this example, an object called `info` is created in the `myApp` module.
When you overwrite the `options.info` function, this has no effect on `myApp.info`, since it was already created and still references the original function.

The quick-and-dirty fix is to override the methods from the `options` module ***before*** you import all other thirdparty modules:

```py
import options
# import myApp  # NOT YET

info_msg = []
warn_msg = []


def info(fmt, ecode, *args):
    info_msg.append(dict({ecode:fmt.format(*args)}))


def warn(fmt, ecode, *args):
    warn_msg.append(dict({ecode:fmt.format(*args)}))

options.warn = warn
options.info = info

import myApp  # Now it's okay


def runApp():
    ...
```

I tested above code with your current example code, and this gives the following output:

```
Start
End
[{100: 'Initialized options'}, {1: 'Running it.'}, {10: 'Inside Process'}, {2: 'Running it.'}]
[]
```

Note, however, that this solution might not work if the actual thirdparty code is bigger and imports are done in an even different way than demonstrated here. Also note that my above code breaks a number of coding styleguides (which you may or may not care about).

---

### Solution using the logging module

Instead of "hacking" the thirdparty code, you can also achieve a similar result using the `logging` module.

The logging module is written to support these type of things, and it seems like the third-party library follows the best practices regarding logging. This means you could just create your own logging handler to deal with logging from the third-party library.

To capture the log messages in the way you demonstrated, you'll need to write a custom logging Handler Object. The following code demonstrates how this works.

```py
import logging

import thirdparty.options  # See note below
import thirdparty.myApp  # See note below


class MyLogHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.info_msg = []
        self.warn_msg = []

    def emit(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        ecode = record.__dict__.get('ecode')
        if record.levelno == logging.INFO:
            self.info_msg.append({ecode: record.msg.format(*record.args)})
        elif record.levelno == logging.WARNING:
            self.warn_msg.append({ecode: record.msg.format(*record.args)})


def runApp():
    handler = MyLogHandler()
    logging.getLogger('thirdparty.options').addHandler(handler)  # See note below
    print("Start")
    thirdparty.options.init()  # See note below
    thirdparty.myApp.runIt()  # See note below
    print("End")
    print(handler.info_msg)
    print(handler.warn_msg)


runApp()
```

*NOTE: I named the thirdparty module "thirdparty" in the above code. Your actual library probably has a different name, in which case you'll need to match the name in the code accordingly!*

The output of above script is:

```
Start
[thirdparty.options] [100] [INFO   ] [2022-06-10 18:06:21,979] Initialized options
[thirdparty.options] [1] [INFO   ] [2022-06-10 18:06:21,979] Running it.
[thirdparty.options] [10] [INFO   ] [2022-06-10 18:06:21,980] Inside Process
[thirdparty.options] [2] [INFO   ] [2022-06-10 18:06:21,980] Running it.
End
[{100: 'Initialized options'}, {1: 'Running it.'}, {10: 'Inside Process'}, {2: 'Running it.'}]
[]
```

Note that this solution does not *replace* the original logging, but *adds* a log handler, so the original logging still works as well. (If you don't want that, you can remove the original log handler.)

References:

- [Library documentation of Handler Object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#handler-objects).
- [Python Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#handlers)

Answer (score -1):

Try having the `import thirdparty.setup` in a function because otherwise you are gonna have an import error.